# Integral with functions as limit

Tags: integration

How can I solve integrals like this :

$$
\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} u(t) dt
$$

I think it has a general formula to solve it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't any different as solving without functions in as limits, just find an antiderivative

$$U(t) = \int u(t)dt$$

and plug in your limits:

$$
\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} u(t) dt = U(f(x))-U(g(x))
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you know $U$ such that 
$$
U'=u
$$ then
$$
\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} u(t) dt=U(f(x))-U(g(x))
$$

Answer (score 0):

$U\left.(t)\right|_{g(x)}^{f(x)}$

Comment: please add some more thoughts on this...otherwise this can hardly be seen as an answer